# Is there any way to debug cordova based windows 10 UWP mobile app?

Tags: cordova, windows-10-universal, remote-debugging, visual-studio-cordova, windows-10-mobile

I have created one cordova based windows 10 UWP mobile application. With the help of cordova command line, able to create build. Installing the build to windows 10 device using device portal. It's  installing successfully, but now I want to debug the application. I can't see any other way through device portal. If someone knows please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can [Debug your app built with Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova](https://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/debug-using-visual-studio/) help you?

Comment: Thanks Sunteen.. Currently I am doing in same way.. but thought like for android we can use chrome and for ios we can use safari.. is there any other way or with the help of internet explorer?